# Unable to copy file into external hard drive: Read-only file system

Tags: macos, terminal

I am trying to save some important files from my faulty internal hard drive on my iMac. I am in the Internet Recovery mode and running the terminal. I also have connected an external 1TB storage and I can view the files inside it using the terminal. However, I cannot seem to write anything on the external drive as I get the message

```
cp: volumes/seagatedrive/backup.dmg: Read-only file system
```

I have used the `chmod 777` command for my *seagatedrive* to no avail. The message I get there is:

> Unable to change file mode on volumes/seagatedrive: Read-only file
>   system

How can I make my external hard drive (*seagatedrive* above) writable?

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: I know this is over a year old now, but in case others come here looking for reasons why they can't write to their external drive: Since it's apparent that you have a Seagate drive, may I point out that you can download the free (Seagate-sponsored) version of Paragon's NTFS utility from here: https://www.seagate.com/au/en/support/downloads/item/ntfs-driver-for-mac-os-master-dl/ - works flawlessly to enable transparent writing of NTFS disks.  I may be wrong but it appears that you just have to have a Seagate drive attached for the utility to install - but you can use it on any drive thereafter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### UPDATE

OP has stated, that his drive is formatted as NTFS. therefore you'll need to setup thirdparty drivers to support write-access on that drive. 
An article about that can be found here: 
http://www.howtogeek.com/236055/how-to-write-to-ntfs-drives-on-a-mac/

[...]
Mac OS X can read from NTFS drives, but it can’t write to them unless you use one of the below tricks. We highly recommend paying for a third-party NTFS driver if you need to do this as the other solutions don’t work as well and are more work to set up.[...]

Alternatively you should consider using exFAT as drive Format. Using
exFAT has the advantage of compatibility on [almost all Platforms](https://kb.sandisk.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3389/kw/exfat).

---

Since I can't put my thoughts in a comment (not enough rep. yet) here is what you can check.

osx behaves strangely with external drives which aren't formatted in Mac OS Format.

- check volume's partition-type
- check mount tab (if exists)
- make shure that your drive isn't write-protected.

if this all fails you could also check, if root has the proper rights to do these previous things.
if so, there might be a problem with your account or privileges on that account.

if there won't be anyone being able to help you, you should try and ask your question on https://unix.stackexchange.com/

cheers and good luck

Comment: The volumes's partition type is `NTFS`- I don't see the mount tab. I do not think the drive is write-protected because I can easily add files to it on my Windows.

Comment: Ntfs is known to be readonly on mac os. it is a limitation by the subsystem.

as long as you don't format your drive as exfat, fat or mac os format, you won't be able to write on that drive.

(don't forget to save your data before formatting!)

Comment: The drive is new so I do not have important files on it. If I erase the drive using `ExFat` will I be able to change Disk Permissions on it?

Comment: I recommend you to format your drive with your Harddisk tool on osx. 
(finder -> applications -> system applications)

exfat is writable under windows, unix, linux  and osx.

if osx' format tool doesn't offer exfat you can format it on your windows machine.

Comment: I do not have access to finder. I am locked outside. My HDD does not work probably. I cannot boot even in safe mode. I am inside the recovery mode now. Should I use the erase option with ExFat?

Comment: I have Windows. Maybe I format the drive with ExFat there, right?

Comment: yep, you can format the drive on windows.

Comment: Thank you. I will try and then come back to you on this.

Comment: Formatting to ExFat seemed to do the trick. Thanks you. You can edit your answer to highlight this if you want.